# Why use push function make the array become to number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I click my `<CheckBox />` will send the id and I use the code:

```
this.setState({
  ids: ids.push(id)
});
```

make my this.state.ids become an ids array.

Click first time looks very well that is an number array

[image]

But when I click another `<CheckBox />` it will show the error

`push is not a function`.

I `console.log('before', ids);` it and check the `typeof` that I found it is a number not an array. I am confused with it. Because when I click the `<CheckBox />` first time. `console.log('after', ids);` is an array not a number.

[image]

Here is my code:

FirstScreen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import FilterComponent from './common/FilterComponent';

const testArray = [
  { id: '0', name: 'test1' },
  { id: '1', name: 'test2' },
  { id: '2', name: 'test3' },
  { id: '3', name: 'test4' },
  { id: '4', name: 'test5' },
  { id: '5', name: 'test6' },
];

class FilterScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ids: []
    };
  }

  getIds = (id) => {
    const { ids } = this.state;
    console.log('before', ids);
    console.log(typeof ids);

    this.setState({
      ids: ids.push(id)
    });
    
    console.log('after', ids);
  }

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <FilterComponent item={item} getIds={this.getIds} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }}
          data={testArray}
          renderItem={this.renderItem} 
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default FilterScreen;
```

FilterComponent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

class FilterComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      checked: false,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { id, name } = this.props.item;
    console.log('component', id);
    return (
      <CheckBox
        title={name}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onPress={() => {
          this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
          if (!this.state.checked) {
            this.props.getIds(id);
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default FilterComponent;
```

Why my `this.state.ids` become to number ?

Comment: `push` returns the new length of the array, not the array itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pushing into an array, then you need to use the same object, like

```
ids.push(id); // now use the object ids
console.log(ids); // => ['1'] if id was 1
```

whereas you are saving the value returned from `push`

```
ids: ids.push(id) // => ids.push(id) will not return an array
// and ids will not be an array after this
```

A workaround would be:

```
this.setState({
  ids: [
    ...this.state.ids,
    id,
  ],
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, it is very clear, but when I try the code and click the <CheckBox /> first time, `console.log('after', this.state.ids);` will be an empty array, any idea ?

Comment: @徐博俊 `setState` is async, so if you do a `console.log` right after, it won't show the updated state. Do a `console.log` inside your `render` method to get the actual state before rendering.

Comment: Ouch, I'm so stupid... That's very clear now  `console.log('under render', this.state.ids);`. Thank you very much @Fawaz, it helps me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to put id into ids.
You can use concat function (return new array always) for that.

```
ids.concat([id])
```

Actually, push function update your original array and return number of items in array.
That's why you are getting 1(number of items in the array) for the first time.

Comment: Thanks, so concat will return an array may the good choice. Thank you very much 
!